# what should I import to use jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using jquery datatable https://www.datatables.net/. 
I just wonder **whether I have to import //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css**?

I just imported https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js. It seems it works too.

The following is a piece of the source codes of my web page on firefox.

```
<table id="reportsTable" class="table dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="reportsTable_info">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="col-md-5 sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="reportsTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Report Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 655px;">Report Name</th>
      <th class="col-md-2 sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="reportsTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Created Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 240px;">Created Date</th>
      <th class="col-md-2 sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="reportsTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Last Modified Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 240px;">Last Modified Date</th>
      <th class="col-md-2 thead-schedule sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Scheduling" style="width: 240px;">Scheduling</th>
      <th class="col-md-1 sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 101px;"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="reportTableBody">
    <tr class="report-entry odd" role="row">
      <td class="sorting_1"><a href="reports/135">dddd123678</a></td>
      <td>
        <time>4/13/2016, 14:41</time>
      </td>
      <td>
        <time>4/14/2016, 14:02</time>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Where do css classes (such as scending, sorting_asc, reportsTable_info, ..) come from?**

Comment: It is not clear what you are saying. *the output html contains css tags defined in the css file.* can you share that output code?

Comment: @Aziz My question is: why some css tags are generated in the output html file, but only the js file imported and ('#example').DataTable() called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [website](https://datatables.net):

> Getting started with DataTables is as simple as including two files in your web-site, the CSS styling and the DataTables script itself.

If you want all of the styling functionality used by DataTables you should include the CSS file.

It also [says](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#Installing-Javascript-/-CSS):

> The CSS file is actually optional, but it provides default styling for your table to make it look good with minimum effort.

The javascript will reference the CSS classes but if you don't have them it won't apply the additional styling.

Comment: It can provide default styling if only js imported?

Comment: If you use the developer tools to inspect those classes, you can see that they probably don't do anything if you don't have the CSS, it just uses basic css styling, not any of the styles the CSS file would use.

Comment: I imported only js file, but the output html contains css tags defined in the css file. Maybe something missing. I am confused.

Comment: You can put anything you want into an HTML css class even if it doesn't exist, just no styling will be applied because that class has no styling tied to it in a css class definition.

Comment: I imported only js file, but the output html contains css tags defined in the css file. For example, sorting_asc. I also found some css tags not defined in css file, such as sorting_disabled.  Maybe something missing. That is why I am confused.

Comment: The class names can still be there even if the css file isn't there. They just won't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Nived. In general when adding jquery libraries, the .js files usually have references to class tags in css.  This means you should use the included .css files.  The good part is that if you want to style things after you just have to include any css definitions after you load the initial file.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

.td{font-size: 12px;}
```

Comment: I imported only js file, but the output html contains css tags defined in the css file. For example, sorting_asc. I also found some css tags not defined in css file, such as sorting_disabled.  Maybe something missing. I am confused.

Comment: @BAE, import CSS file using `link` tag placed in the `head` section of your html as the answer suggests.